# Problem converting C# programming language to vb .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox, converters

I have a piece of code in C # that I converted to Visual Basic, but unfortunately I can not convert part of this code to Visual Basic and I have not been able to do so even using online converters.
I have an event that I had trouble to call it.
my code is:

```
Private Sub TextBoxListViewTextTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If _subtitleListViewIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim numberOfNewLines As Integer = textBoxListViewText.Text.Length - textBoxListViewText.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Length
            Utilities.CheckAutoWrap(textBoxListViewText, New KeyEventArgs(Keys.None), numberOfNewLines)
            Dim text As String = textBoxListViewText.Text.TrimEnd()
            _subtitle.Paragraphs(_subtitleListViewIndex).Text = text
            SubtitleListView1.SetText(_subtitleListViewIndex, text)
            _listViewTextUndoIndex = _subtitleListViewIndex
            StartUpdateListSyntaxColoring()
        End If
    End Sub
```

But here I have a problem because I can not call directly:

```
Private Sub InitializeListViewEditBox(ByVal p As Paragraph)

        textBoxListViewText.TextChanged -= TextBoxListViewTextTextChanged()
       
End Sub
```

I have no idea how I can solve this problem.

Comment: [RemoveHandler Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement) -- IMO, you should rewrite that code. Is that a Custom Control you found somewhere?

Comment: @Jimi Dear Jimi, It was great, thank you for your guidance, this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
RemoveHandler textBoxListViewText.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBoxListViewTextTextChanged
```

and

```
AddHandler textBoxListViewText.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBoxListViewTextTextChanged
```

Comment: Dear Fawlty thank you very much It was great, this is exactly what I wanted.